# How to do this query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I have problem for create SQL. I have table and the data like this :

```
id month year id_type qty
1   10   2012   1      5
2   10   2012   2      4
3   10   2012   3      3 
4   10   2012   4      5
5   11   2012   1      1
6   11   2012   2      2
7   12   2012   1      3
8   12   2012   2      2
```

I want create SQL for generating the data like this

```
id_type month year qty month_b4 year_b4 qty_b4
  1       10   2012  5    9       2012    0
  2       10   2012  4    9       2012    0        
  3       10   2012  3    9       2012    0        
  4       10   2012  5    9       2012    0        
  1       11   2012  1    10      2012    5
  2       11   2012  2    10      2012    4
  1       12   2012  1    11      2012    1                
  2       12   2012  2    11      2012    2
```

Comment: Where are month_b4, etc... coming from?

Comment: they are coming from the same table..

Comment: What's the relation among the fields? month_b4 appears to be one less than the month, and I assume year_b4 is one less than the year provided the month takes you into the previous year, but what about qty_b4?

Comment: qty_b4 is the qty from previous month

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  So basically, the other columns are a query from the same table for the same id but the previous month and year (where applicable)?

Comment: Yeap, I just want's get the qty from the previous month

Answer (score 0):

This query will do it:

```
select 
  sales.id_type as id_type,
  sales.month as month,
  sales.year as year,
  sales.qty as qty,
  prev.month as month_b4,
  prev.year as year_b4,
  prev.qty as qty_b4
from 
  sales,
  sales as prev
where
  sales.id_type = prev.id_type and
  ((sales.month=1 and prev.month=12 and prev.year=sales.year-1) or 
     prev.month = sales.month - 1);
```

I also have it on a fiddle where you can experiment with it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed3af/14